# Gain root access via putty cmd

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm facing a problem here, I'd like to use putty cmd to execute script on my remote server, just like below.
putty.exe -ssh [domain] -l [user] -pw [password] hello.pl

However it's required a root permission to execute it. Is there any way to gain a root permission when use putty cmd as default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `user` should be `root`, and `password` should be the password for root - obviously, you can only use this approach if you know root's password, and it is a bit insecure so I don't recommend it. If root doesn't have a password, you can set one with `sudo passwd`.

If root logins are disallowed in the server's configuration, you can:

1. use `sudo hello.pl` as the command, and disable asking for the password in `/etc/sudoers`
2. or set the `setuid` bit on `hello.pl`. (Note that this may be disallowed by the operating system for security reasons!)

However, both ways may require assistance from your system administrator, if you have one.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, other way to type root password via cmd, actually I don't care about the security. :)